# Why do I get error: RPC failed; result=52, HTTP code = 0 fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly when pushing to github?

Tags: git, github, push, git-remote

I created a new repository on `github` and wanted to push some files. So I initialize the repository like normal and do `git add .` to add the current directory (which is my `java` project folder with `bin` and `src` folder inside). Then I added the remote directory using:

```
git remote add https://github.com/username/project.git
```

Then I made my first commit `git commit -m "First Commit"`

then I type `git push -u origin master` and I get this error:

```
Counting objects: 63, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (60/60), done.
Writing objects: 100% (62/62), 16.98 KiB, done.
Total 62 (delta 15), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; result=52, HTTP code = 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

But if I add just one file and try to commit just a single file, it works.

What is going on? Why can I not commit my whole Java project? Its a pretty small project only 214k. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Do you `git commit` the whole project as well after you `git add .`?

Comment: yup I commited the whole project. So github is down now, and I just checked on twitter and others are getting the same error. I wonder if it is a problem on their part?

Comment: try to do a GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push and see the error? https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=301663267

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Now it is working! I didn't even change a thing.

This kind of an error ' result=52 ' is an error with github itself. Github.com was going down and when I tried uploading I got the error. Now the site is back up and I can commit like normal.

Comment: bitbucket was with the same error, but returned after a few minutes.
Good response.

Answer (score 20):

Bitbucket has the same error message. Often it is related to degraded server performance. Before you start doing anything else, check:

- https://bitbucket.status.atlassian.com/
- https://www.githubstatus.com/

Comment: upvoted! This is usefull, and can avoid some time wasting. thx

Answer (score 16):

This error also happens if your `HTTP` post buffer is too small for the changes you want to push.

In this case, the solution is to increase it, for example using

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Comment: It should be git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000

Comment: Hi Michael, it depends on whether you want to change your configuration for the current repository or whether you want to change your default setting. If you pass the --global flag, it writes to the .gitconfig file in your user directory. Otherwise, it writes to the repository specific .git/config file.

Comment: Why not? are you saying bitbucket does not honour this client side configuration? There are many reasons a remote git server will drop a connection, the post buffer size being too small is just one of many reasons - although a common one.

Comment: @Dughall I am getting same error for git pull. I tried this -git config http.getBuffer 524288000 , However this didn't work any suggestion for this?

Comment: @PHcoDer, you can get the same problem whether you're pulling or pushing; sometimes, git might fail silently if it can not update your configuration. So I would run git config -list to ensure that your buffer setting is actually what you expect.

Comment: If it is not what you expect, it's probably a permissions problem preventing git from updating the config file. Try running it as an administrator to update your configuration. If it is as you expect, there must be another reason why the connection is being dropped.

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this problem when trying to clone/fetch from a Bitbucket repository over http. It turns out **the repository is too big** (+1gb) and Bitbucket replies with this error:

```
error: RPC failed; result=52, HTTP code = 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I switched to the SSH protocol and now it works fine. Afterwards, you can set the remote back to the http version if you need to, and it will keep working.

Comment: could not make it work with ssh, permission denied error

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov You need to configure an SSH key for your Bitbucket account. Check [these instructions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html) on how to do that.

Comment: This is actually the answer, even though others have more up-votes, if you're cloning a massive repo.

Comment: @JesseQ My anwser doesn't actually answer the original question, since his or her repository obviously wasn't big. But it's the same error many people get, so they end up here anyway.

Comment: @FerryBoender it likely does/will solve the OP issue so in my book, it's +1.  Regardless, it solved my problem with a large repository and wanted to make sure others give this a try.

Answer (score 6):

This could happen if you have a faulty internet connection too, Yeah I am experiencing one at this time.. :).

Answer (score 3):

I tried this:

```
$ git config --global --add core.compression -1
$ git clone https://....
```

and it worked.

(Found [here](https://cristinallamas.wordpress.com/2013/11/02/git-error-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly/))

Answer (score 3):

This can be also due to the following

Reason

> Prescence of large files (45MB in our case)

Why

> Large files cause HTTPS Timeout

Solution

> Use SSH or Remove large files

Answer (score 0):

For **Bitbucket**, I resolve this with switch to ssh instead of http.

1. Configure `SECURITY > SSH keys` in `Avatar > Bitbucket settings` :
2. Change remote url from `https://...` to `git@...`

   - Edit `.git/config` file **OR** launch `git remote set-url origin git@...`
3. `git push -u origin --all` (NB: `git add .` follow by `git commit -m "intial commit"` before)

*based on [wintersolider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3292325/wintersolider)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38763056/4457531)*

Answer (score 0):

It took me hours. I had the same problem using https. Plus: I could not connect to bitbucket via ssh.

I'm using Linux Mint 17.x and this solution worked like a charm for ssh:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/1254085 (answer from bs – bentzy-sagiv)

> This solved the issue:
>
> Append to /etc/sysctl.conf the following:
>   net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing = 1
>
> after restart you should see at /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_mtu_probing the
>   value "1"
>
> A temporary solution is: echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_mtu_probing
>   caveat: this will be reset at boot.
>
> You can try also with value "2" if still not working.
>
> (see explanation
>   at:https://thesimplecomputer.info/pages/adventures-in-linux-tcp-tuning-page2)