# why gitlab refuse push pdf file?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-push

I'm stuck the problem a whole day when push my project to gitlab.Finally, I find it push success when ignore `*.pdf`.
I have test a single .pdf file can't push to gitlab.Error like this:

```
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 56.31 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; result=52, HTTP code = 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

The info `error: RPC failed; result=52, HTTP code = 0` says server refuse the request by some problem. I don't know detail about it.
Besides, the pdf just 1M so its not problem of size limit like some other `result=52` question.
Does someone know why gitlab refuse pdf(maybe other specify file not meet yet)?
Does it has some config file to setting allow file format? 
Thanks any advice.

**========== Update ============**
So amazing, my PC can't reproduce ths issue but my colleague does. The ouput with `$ GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push origin master` as this:

```
10:29:07.766853 pkt-line.c:80           packet:         push< 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 capabilities^{}\0report-status delete-refs side-band-64k quiet atomic ofs-delta agent=git/2.7.4
10:29:07.768806 pkt-line.c:80           packet:         push< 0000
10:29:07.769813 pkt-line.c:80           packet:         push> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 a8fb09a3761d21949c7a36b3111fa9fadeddeb59 refs/heads/master\0 report-status side-band-64k agent=git/2.7.0.windows.1
10:29:07.769813 pkt-line.c:80           packet:         push> 0000
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 784.55 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Connection reset by 192.168.1.2
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

both of our git version is **2.7.0.windows.1**, origin is ssh channel.

The network is not so bad but I not sure it's health.
Can you get some further infomation form the error output?Thanks again.

Comment: Running with `GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push origin master` might give you more details about what is happening.  It's definitely odd that it's claiming everything is up-to-date after what appear to be fatal errors. :-(  BTW, you should probably mention what version of Git you're using.  I know several curl-related issues have been fixed in some fairly recent versions.

Comment: @jszakmeister,It works when I add `GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push origin master` and the later push become normal! I really carzy now. what did I do today.

Comment: @jszakmeister, my colleague also has the problem,I will test again on his machine at tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

The error message `RPC failed; result=52` is not specific to Gitlab and is related to file size or network performance. It is very common and may be caused by different reasons:

- You are trying to push through HTTP a repository too big. If this is your case, switch to SSH and try again.
- The origin server have a temporary performance problem. So just try again latter.
- Your internet connection is slow or with high latency. Try to fix this.

See also:
[Why do I get error: RPC failed; result=52, HTTP code = 0 fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly when pushing to github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436812/why-do-i-get-error-rpc-failed-result-52-http-code-0-fatal-the-remote-end-h)

Comment: I has refresh my problem with new output.The error occurred under SSH and tried 2 times in my colleague, at the same time, my PC works well and his computer work on other network things no problem.Can you get some info form the error message?thanks

Comment: It may just be that the file is too big and thus takes too long?